# How to check if a share is being used (some copying happening etc. ) before invoking " net use /delete "

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I am new to world of scripting. I have been using `net use` in my background jobs in powershell to copy files to a shared folder from multiple locations.

there is a restriction on number of shares that be created at a time hence on finishing copying of a job I go ahead and delete the share. But one cavet here is it must not be deleted of any other copying is happening.

Appreciate if any one can help me to figure out a way to have a check to use `net use /delete` only if no copy operations etc are happening to shared folder else wait till it completes and then delete the share.

Best regards !

Answer (score 0):

```
net use x: /delete /n
```

If any file is in use, `net use` will ask for permission to disconnect. Use the `/n` parameter to answer No to the question

Comment: unfortunately in powershell this is not asking for permission. Hence I am stuck with getting erros from other jobs copying while this gets deleted.

Comment: @Anand, from powershell invoke the native `net.exe` to do the work for you.